# Assign List<B> object to List<A> object

Tags: list, hibernate, maven, mapping

I have a problem that I want to know if there is a magic trick or pattern to solve this in the other way.

I have list of B class objects, but I need to return list of A class objects. 'A' and 'B' classes have exactly the same fields (I need to return List, but I have List because it was mapped from database by hibernate) and I need to return it inside List of A objects because I can not import B class to other project (where class A is) beacuse of maven cyclic reference.

I just rewrote all fields from every object in for loop.

Is there any other way to solve this without doing it inside the loop?

Thanks in advance for discussion :)
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try returning Object type list? It could then be type-casted to B type .

Comment: Welcome to SO. if you seek clarifications from asker or giving suggestions, then put it in comments. In answer you should have concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world you would extend both classes from one base class to make them copatible, but i see that this is not possible here.

in my opinion your approch is already the savest way to solve the problem.

another way would be to solve it over reflection. It's not recomendable - just pointing this out.

In this solution, you iterate over all declared fields of the given object, read out the value and set the field with the same name in your object to this value.

like i said, it's not recomendable because it relies on field names which may change.